# How to I call a method to create arrays from another class?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this code in the main class

```
    public class OneDArrays
{
    public static int[] create (int size)
    {
        int[] a1 = new int[size];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            a1[i] = i*2+1;
        }
        return a1;
    }
    
    public int sumSome (int[] b1, int howmany)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if (howmany <= b1.length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + b1[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sum = -1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    
    public int[] grow (int[] c1, int extra)
    {
        int[] newArray = new int[c1.length+extra];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)
        {
            while (i <= c1.length)
            {
                newArray[i] = c1[i];
                i++;
            }
            newArray[i] = 0;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
    
    public void print (int[] d1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < d1.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println (d1[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have my tester class,

```
public class OneDArraysTester
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] test1;
        
        test1.create (5);
    }
}
```

How do retrieve the method from the first class? I get the error that "create" is an undeclared method. If the "create" method were a constructer, I know I could just type `create test1 = new create (5)` but I don't see a way to turn it in to a constructer, so what's the way of doing that but for a method?

Answer (score 0):

You invoke a static method with the classname. Literally `className.methodName`. Like,

```
int[] test1 = OneDArrays.create(5);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I'm not slow I promise, I definitely tried something along these lines before but I guess the syntax of it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a class named `OneDArrays` so you can call it's methods by creating an instance or object of that class.
like this :

```
OneDArrays ObjectOfClass = new OneDArrays();
int test1[] = ObjectOfClass.create(5);
```

similarly you can also call other methods of that class by accessing methods of this newly created object `ObjectOfClass`.
like :

```
sumOfArray = ObjectOfClass.sumSome(test1,3);
int biggerTest1[] = ObjectOfClass.grow(test1,10);
```

If you want to make create method works as a constructor than you can but you cannot return value from a constructor so you cannot return your array from that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared the `create` method as static, @ElliotFrisch is the best way. But, it is not always a good idea to make methods static. So another way to achieve what you want would be to make the `create` method non-static.

```
public int[] create (int size){/*Method Body*/};
```

And then create an object of the `OneDArray` class to access the method.

```
OneDArrays oneDArrays = new OneDArrays();
int[] test1 = oneDArrays.create(5);
```

or,

```
int[] test1 = new OneDArrays().create(5);
```